# How to use ffmpeg overlay to add 2 videos and set delay timing on them?

Tags: ffmpeg

i'm new to ffmpeg and still learning. I want to add a overlay of 2 videos to my main video. one is a logo/text animation video and the other is a like,subscribe etc button video. And i want them to show on a specific time i set them but have no idea how to do this.

Also i want to position them to where i want them to appear and size as well. Can someone guide me on this. I read some articles but not sure how to get it done or what number i should change etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this code:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=100:150[ovrl],[0:0][ovrl]overlay=enable='between(t\,5,10)':x=10:y=100[out]"  -shortest -map [out] -map 0:1 output2.mp4
```

`[1:v]scale=100:150` set the size of watermark to 100x150 pixel.

`overlay=100:10` is the position of the watermark video (X=100, Y=10)

`overlay=enable='between(t\,5,10)'` determines the time of showing the watermark video(between 5 sec to 10 sec).

Comment: Hi thank you for the fast reply. i will try this out. How do i let the overlay video to run till it finishes? Meaning lets say i want it to start at 5 secs and it's 20 secs long and than let the main video continue. Or i'll have to specify the overlay's video length? thanks alot!

Comment: ffmpeg -i 1min.mp4 -i intro.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=100:150[ovrl],[0:0][ovrl]overlay=enable='between(t\,0,20)':x=10:y=100[out]"  -shortest -map [out] -map 0:1 output2.mp4   , i used this and got the error : Stream map '0:1' matches no streams.
To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map. Please advise. i set video to start at 0 sec and end at 20 secs.